# How to turn intellisense on in JCreator?

Tags: java, jcreator

I have installed JCreator 5.0 (jcreator.com)
I dont know how to turn intellisense on in JCreator. Moreover, errors are not marked. I skimmed options but I havent found the right option.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

There is not default intellisense on JCreator. You should download and use JCreator Pro for that.

Answer (score 0):

JCreator's [official forums](http://www.jcreator.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=8117) didn't seem to provide much help even with the licensed version.

Perhaps you might consider another free Java IDE that has autocompletion (aka, intellisense) built-in such as [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/), or [IntelliJ Community Edition](http://www.jetbrains.org/)?